# How/When is the HOME environment variable set within R

Tags: r

Asked on [superuser](https://superuser.com/questions/1371373/how-when-is-the-home-environment-variable-set-within-r) and got crickets, so trying here. This one seems to straddle the border of SU/SO.

In troubleshooting some kind of R configuration issue that was causing a pandoc conversion failure when trying to Knit a .Rmd on a colleague's Windows 10 machine, I noticed that the first path in `.libPaths()` was pointing to a path on a network directory rather than the `c:/Users/[username]/R/win-library/...` directory.

Running `Sys.getenv()` in R showed that `HOMEDRIVE` and `HOMEPATH` were (as expected) `c:` and `\Users\[username]`, yet there was a `HOME` environment variable listed that was pointing to the network path that we'd found in `.libPaths()`

Running `SET` in a cmd shell did not list this `HOME` environment variable at all, so it seems to be something that R found somewhere else...

Where does R get this `HOME` environment variable?

FWIW: I fixed the config issue by setting a Windows User Environment variable HOME=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%; R then set all the other environment variables appropriately from there.

Comment: http://astrostatistics.psu.edu/su07/R/html/base/html/Startup.html

Comment: `R` usually uses the Documents folder of the current user for home on windows. I sometimes saw that Windows is configured to place the Documents folder on a network drive. I usually set a User Environment variable on these machines. Not sure if this helps but at least no crickets...

Comment: @hrbrmstr I reviewed that reference multiple times and chased down all the various possible config and initialization files, and I still didn't find a smoking gun.

Comment: @JBGruber I think you're on to something here, and I suspected much the same, as the network directory in question did look like a Documents folder, but I haven't yet found the "cause" of this; i.e. where's the code or config file that is setting `HOME` on R startup?

Comment: R is starting up as a process after everything else OS-wise is set. so whatever is in `HOME` when the process kicks off is what R is going to see, no? Does Windows do something different, now?

Comment: `src/gnuwin32/system.c` (where a bunch of env var stuff happens) doesn't appear to be doing anything abnormal except Windows systems calls.

Comment: @hrbrmastr on the subject machine, initially `HOME` was not set at the OS level, R was picking something else (source and logic unknown) to set to `HOME`, and this was creating problems.  I worked around the issue by setting a Windows User environment variable `HOME=%HOMEDRIVE%%HOMEPATH%`, which R then picked up as you describe. The question is: what was the initial logic and source that R used to create a session-local `HOME` environment variable when it was not set at the OS level?

Comment: @mac Hi,did you find the answer?

Comment: @cloudscomputes the accepted answer below cleared it all up for me

Answer (score 8, accepted):

R startup is somewhat complicated, but it is pretty well documented. The usual starting place is `help("Startup")`. The answer to your question is not documented there, but you will find this clue in the *See also* section:

> For the definition of the ‘home’ directory on Windows see the ‘rw-FAQ’
>   Q2.14. It can be found from a running R by Sys.getenv("R_USER")

and indeed the cited FAQ at https://cran.r-project.org/bin/windows/base/rw-FAQ.html#What-are-HOME-and-working-directories_003f gives us the answer:

> The home directory is set as follows: If environment variable R_USER
>   is set, its value is used. Otherwise if environment variable HOME is
>   set, its value is used. After those two user-controllable settings, R
>   tries to find system-defined home directories. It first tries to use
>   the Windows "personal" directory (typically
>   C:\Users\username\Documents). If that fails, if both environment
>   variables HOMEDRIVE and HOMEPATH are set (and they normally are), the
>   value is ${HOMEDRIVE}${HOMEPATH}. If all of these fail, the current
>   working directory is used.

Comment: Nailed it! Somehow all my reading and frantic googling failed me on this one. Thanks!

Comment: This seems tells us how the home directory is set rather than how the HOME env is set. Even you didn't find HOME in OS's system env var, you will see it in your R session when you start R using Rstudio

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at [the here package](https://here.r-lib.org/) and, relating to knitr, [the ezknitr package.](https://www.r-bloggers.com/ezknitr-r-package-to-avoid-the-typical-working-directory-pain-when-using-knitr/) Also, in RStudio, you can specify in the knit menu if the knitting will happen in the current dir, working dir or project dir, [as shown here](https://community.rstudio.com/t/how-to-correctly-specify-relative-path/9612).

Update: let me reiterate the message here since it got downvoted: in a typical usage scenario you don't have to modify the HOME environment variable. Using a proper workflow (e.g. RStudio projects or the here package) is a more robust and portable solution.

Answer (score 0):

By default,I mean if you didn't touch .Renviron or .Renviron.site

I believe in windows HOME is set according to some info in regedit,since someone changed it for me and my HOME var changed since then.

In linux,it will take system's env var, normally HOME = /home/username

I don't know for the MAC case.